# $2a^2-1$ doesn't have a divisor of the form $b^2+2 $

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove that $2a^2-1$ doesn't have a divisor of the form $b^2+2 $.

I think that we will use the notion of order somewhere in the proof but I don't know how?

If we just set $$2a^2\equiv 1\pmod{b^2+2}$$
That didn't give us any info.

Comment: Do you know about quadratic residues modulo $p$?

Answer (score 1):

**Sketch of the proof.**

Let $p$ be an arbitrary prime divisor of $b^2+2$. Then, of course, $p\mid 2a^2-1$.
It is clear that $p\neq 2$. From $2a^2-1\equiv b^2+2\equiv 0\pmod p$ we obtain (*how?*)
$$
\left(\frac{2}{p}\right)=\left(\frac{-1}{p}\right)=1.
$$
Thus, $p\equiv 1\pmod 8$ (*why?*). In other words, every prime divisor of $b^2+2$ is of the form $8k+1$, so $b^2+2\equiv 1\pmod 8$ which is impossible (*why?*).